# Spring mvc web application not working as required

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a simple web application using Spring mvc to do the following:

-A page with a form for the user to enter their name  and submit

-User should be redirected to a new page on form submission with a message as below
Hello , you are  years old.

I've written the following code but however, my IDE says that the class form is not being used and my output is not AS expected i.e., when I type my Name to the form, it isn't redirecting to another page and displaying "Hello,${name}" as required and expected from the code i've written below. I am quite new to this so,Can someone please help me understand what's wrong?

@Controller

public class form {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getForm(ModelMap model) {
    return "form";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/form",method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String putForm(ModelMap model,  @RequestParam String name,int age){
    model.put("name",name);
    model.put("age",age);
    return "index";
}
```

}

[FORM.HTML FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50Lot.png)

[INDEX.HTML FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlXRM.png)

POM.XML:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.DemoApp.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demoWebApp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demoWebApp</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Does age need @RequestParams

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't work

Comment: Hi & Welcome to [so]! (Html) `<input/>`s *should be* inside a(n html) `<form/>` (which has also attributes as "method" (GET(<-default), POST,PUT,...) and "action" (some absolute or relative url or a placeholder... no "action" means (submit to)"same url" (`action=""`)) ..take a quick [html-tour](https://www.w3schools.com/html/)! ;)

Comment: ..so having an html called "form.html" without any <form/> inside *is suspicious*! ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! But i am still confused on what i should put for action. What do you suggest i put action??

Comment: Now, After i hit submit, its giving the output - Hello ${name}, how you doin? Its not replacing ${name} with the name we enter. Can someone please help me resolve this